# How to resize the calander flutter_calendar_carousel 2.4.2?

Tags: flutter, image, date, calendar, highlight

I want the calander size display smaller. i try to change the height but its not resize the calender, then i change the container height but the calander not displaying the whole calander, we need to scroll.

[image]